# json - вывести только нужные данные

Tags: php, json, foreach, вывод, json-encode

Как пропустить одно (2,3) значение при получении json?

В коде ниже нужно получить только вторые данные — **"dt":1453798800**. При выводе данных с foreach, он выводить весь список. А нужно чтобы выводилось определенные значения. Например 2, 5 и 7.

```js
{  
   "city":{  
      "id":542420,
      "name":"Krasnodar",
      "coord":{  
         "lon":38.976944,
         "lat":45.03278
      },
      "country":"RU",
      "population":0
   },
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0.0252,
   "cnt":2,
   "list":[  
      {  
         "dt":1453712400,
         "temp":{  
            "day":-10.11,
            "min":-15.76,
            "max":-9.67,
            "night":-15.76,
            "eve":-11.65,
            "morn":-10
         },
         "pressure":1035.45,
         "humidity":99,
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":600,
               "main":"Snow",
               "description":"небольшой снегопад",
               "icon":"13d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":4.66,
         "deg":25,
         "clouds":64,
         "snow":0.61
      },
      {  
         "dt":1453798800,
         "temp":{  
            "day":-10.46,
            "min":-17.77,
            "max":-9.26,
            "night":-17.77,
            "eve":-12.58,
            "morn":-14.58
         },
         "pressure":1035.15,
         "humidity":96,
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":600,
               "main":"Snow",
               "description":"небольшой снегопад",
               "icon":"13d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":3.41,
         "deg":68,
         "clouds":24,
         "snow":0.17
      }
   ]
}
```

PHP

```
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $dataJson = json_decode($data);
    $arrayDays = $dataJson->list;

    // выводим данные
    foreach($arrayDays as $oneDay){

      echo "Погода: " . $oneDay->weather[0]->description . "<br/>";
      echo "Скорость ветра: " . $oneDay->speed . "<br/>";
      echo "Давление: " . $oneDay->pressure . "<br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как поле `list` в вашем случае - массив, то выбрать нужные элементы можно прост по индексу

```
var el0 = data.list[0];
var el1 = data.list[1];
//и т.д.
```

Либо воспользоваться функцией [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) и получить массив с нужными элементами

```
var list = data.list.filter(function(element, index){
    return index == 2 || index==5 || index==7; //выбираем элемент только с индексом 2,5 или 7
})
```

**UPDATE:**
Пример с [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) для php

```
var_dump(array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
    return $k == 2 || $k ==5 || $k ==7;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

например:

```
$arrayDays = array_filter($dataJson->list, function($v, $k) {
    return $k == 2 || $k ==5 || $k ==7;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Обратите внимание: флаг, третий параметр, добавлен в версии 5.6.0

Comment: Прошу прощения, я так понимаю это JS? Я использую PHP.

Comment: @RomanPererva, стоит указать это в тегах :-) но суть остается той же - можно либо напрямую обращаться к нужным элементам по индексам, либо отфильтровать массив

Comment: @RomanPererva, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за быстрые ответы. Обновил код в вопросе. Можете пожалуйста подсказать куда вставить ваше решение для PHP.

Comment: @RomanPererva, в место где list получаете

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать сейчас.